# How to get value by Key in List<Dictionary<string,string>> in C#

Tags: c#

I have this List:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> testList= new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

So how to get the value from every Dictionary?

I know I can get the Dictionary by index like:

```
testList[index]
```

But I don't know how to get a value by key from `Dictionary`.

Comment: Have you tried testList[index][key]?

Comment: oh yes that works thanks! I wonder why nobody had this problem. I googled 10min without success

Comment: Because you could have just googled [c# dictionary](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=c%23+dictionary) and gone to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx). Then scroll down to [Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: just toxic stackoverflow...

Answer (score 2):

With

```
var value = testList[index][key]
```

you will get the value from the dictionary inside the list.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
testList[int][TKey]
```

`Dictionary<object, object>` has an item propety `Item[TKey]`:

```
testList[int].Add("apple", 1);

if (testList[int].ContainsKey("apple"))
{
    int value = testList[int]["apple"];
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```